# A way to render content to a base template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a base template which contains header, footer and a block "content" which then I override in different CBVs.

There is little "user-space" `div`inside a header where I want to keep user's info in case he is logged in and a login form if he is a guest.

Right now the only way that comes in mind is to create a django app and use it as a tag. But I think there is a better solution. Because as far as I know tags can slow down django project in future.

Also I think that maybe I would like to manipulate this `div` from a view which renders a child template. For example I calculate and display some value on a page but also I want to display it in a "user-space" `div` as well. I think this can be achieved by pushing data to the user's session and then using this while rendering "user-space" `div` from another code.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `django.contrib.auth.user` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can access the user's login status using [`user.is_authenticated()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div>Welcome back, {{ user.username }} | <a href='/logout/'>Logout</a></div>
{% else %}
    <div>
    <form action='/login/' method='POST'>
    {{ csrf_token }}
    {{ login_form }}
    <input type='submit'>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**Edit**:

In response to your comment:

> Let's suppose client does a POST request by which we calculate some number - total price. And I need to display it in that div.

[As documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#the-view)

Define your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MyForm

def simple_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            result = form.cleaned_data['some_input'] * 50
            return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'result': result})

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'my_other_template.html', {'form': form})
```

Display `result` in your template:

```
<!-- my_template.html -->
<div>{{ result }}</div>
```

Maybe you need to be more specific with your question, this is what I think you are looking for though. You should put logic like you are describing into a view, not a template.

Comment: Of course, this assumes you have [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) enabled as a template context processor in your settings.

Comment: What if i want to add here some custom data as I mentioned in a question?  The question wasn't really about a particular user-login-stuff example, but more about a general picture. How to self implement what does the auth.user app do. It uses inclusion tags?

Comment: @Glueon What does your user model look like and what are you trying to include? If you have seen an example and you want to know how it works, why not look at its source code?

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist I want to understand how can change context data in base template. Let's suppose client does a POST request by which we calculate some number - total price. And I need to display it in that `div`.

Comment: I dont know what this means: "Right now the only way that comes in mind is to create a django app and use it as a tag. But I think there is a better solution. Because as far as I know tags can slow down django project in future."

Comment: I don't know that you can edit context data within a template, I don't see any time you would want to do that in a template and not in a view. Get your logic into the view and out of the template, it makes them unreadable and performance will improve marginally too I think.

Comment: @web-student-ksu
Now suppose that your `my_template.html` extends `base.html` and `{{ result }}` is in a `base.html`. How do I push context['result'] there? I thought `{{result}}` in `base.html` is not available to me when view renders another template, even if it extends `base.html`

Comment: Never tried that, but I'm very sure the same context is available in all rendered templates. the `{{ result }}` tag would render the same in any template. Note this also applies to included templates: `{% include 'yet_another_template.html' %}`